# Is Scala's Try referentially transparent?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, side-effects, referential-transparency

I'm currently working on a presentation about Functional Programming, and came upon the following problem.

Functional Programming intends to separate the 'what' from the 'how', or more precisely, the declaration of a computation from its interpretation. This is why one of the main focus of this paradigm is to represent computations using composable data-structures without making any assumptions about how they are performed. For example:

```
// Represents a computation that may fail
case class Unsafe[A,B](run: A => B)

// ...
val readIntFromFile: Unsafe[String, Int] = Unsafe { filePath => /* ... */ }
interpret(readIntFromFile)

// Interpreter
def interpret(u: Unsafe[String, Int]): Unit = {
  try {
    u.run("path/to/file")
  } catch {
    case e => /* ... */
  }
}
```

This seems to make sense, as side-effects should be only performed during the execution of the computation and not during its declaration. The problem is that in Scala, as it seems, many data-structures break this rule:

```
object Try {
  /** Constructs a `Try` using the by-name parameter.  This
   * method will ensure any non-fatal exception is caught and a
   * `Failure` object is returned.
   */
  def apply[T](r: => T): Try[T] =
    try Success(r) catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e)
    }
}
```

Same for `Futures`:

```
  /** Starts an asynchronous computation and returns a `Future` object with the result of that computation.
  *
  *  The result becomes available once the asynchronous computation is completed.
  *
  *  @tparam T       the type of the result
  *  @param body     the asynchronous computation
  *  @param executor  the execution context on which the future is run
  *  @return         the `Future` holding the result of the computation
  */
  def apply[T](body: =>T)(implicit @deprecatedName('execctx) executor: ExecutionContext): Future[T] = impl.Future(body)
```

So, I'm wondering now, are `Try` and `Future` really referentially transparent? If not, then how should one handle the error cases without relying on `Success` and `Failure`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try is referentially transparent as long as you don't use side effects.  The purpose of Try is not to control side effects, but to handle a possible exception.

If you need to control side effects in a pure way you can use Task or IO types from libraries like Cats and Scalaz.

Comment: I would also add this: I feel that most of the time, `Try` is the wrong abstraction, and that `Either` and `IO` are more accurate.

Comment: @FrancisToth I think that's more or less correct.  `Try` is basically like declaring "throws exception".  It's better than not documenting the error case at all, but doen't give you any extra information beyond that, and unlike `Either` it requires that your error case is an exception.  `IO/Task` on the other hand handles a completely different problem.

Comment: If we think about the situations when exceptions are really needed, we end up only with IO's or java libraries that are built on exceptions. I mean, when you have control on the code, you don't throw exceptions, right? You return typed meaningful errors. So it seems that `Try` is some kind of glue between Scala/FP and Java.

Answer (score 1):

`Future` is definitely not RT, since these two block are not equivalent:

1. The two futures are executed in parallel:

   ```
   val fa: Future[Int] = service.call
   val fb: Future[Int] = service.call

   for { a <- fa; b <- fb } yield a + b
   ```
2. The two futures are executed in sequentially:

   ```
   for { a <- service.call; b <- service.call } yield a + b
   ```

`Try` is, on the other hand. The proper functional way to handle error is to use `Either[ErrorDescription, A]` for a method that returns an `A` but might fail (you could use `type ErrorDescription = Throwable` for something equivalent to `scala.util.Try`!).

Comment: That's what I don't get. Why is Try referentially transparent? What about a Try that performs a write in a file? This is definitely an 'observable interaction with the outside world', right? So then, from a pure FP point of view, shouldn't we stop relying on pattern matching Tries?

Comment: Is `Option` RT? What about `Option[Unit]` that performs a write in a file?

Comment: The answer above makes sense, both Option and Try do not attempt to handle side-effects. So it's really a matter of using the right abstraction for the right case. Otherwise no matter what you do, you end up in the questioning we just had. Thank you for your help :)